# How to append character to the end of a string without creating a new line

Tags: powershell

I am trying to generate a random string of numbers between 16 and 32 characters here is my code

```
$seedNum = @(16..32)
$times = $seedNum | Get-Random
while ($times -gt 0) {
    $getRandomNum = @(0..9) | Get-Random | Out-String
    $seed = $seed += $getRandomNum
    $times = $times - 1
}

echo $seed > seed.txt
Read-Host
```

3
5
0
7
8
2
1
2
3
5
4
7
5
0
5
5
6

This is the output I get but I want this: 35078212354750556

how can I get it to append the text to the end without creating a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to change in your code. First, `Out-String` adds a new line character to the string so you can do `$getRandomNum.ToString()` instead to get the string without the new line. Second, you only need `$seed += $getRandomNum.ToString()` to add the new number to the string.

Here's the fixed code in it's entirety:

```
while ($times -gt 0) {
    $getRandomNum = @(0..9) | Get-Random
    $seed += $getRandomNum.ToString()
    $times = $times - 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you I had researched Out-String and it said it had a -NoNewLine argument but when I tried that it gave me a syntax error so I figured this might be the issue but I didn’t know how to fix it

Comment: You're right, it does have that option, but I prefer to not use `Out-String` at all. `ToString()` is an option in almost any programming language so that's what I'm used to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way as a one liner.

```
0..(Get-Random(15..31))|foreach{$str=$null;$get={Get-Random(0..9)}}{$str="$(& $get)$str"}{$str}
```

In long form with explanations

```
# overall length of the string. When combined with 0.. it will be 0..15 up to 0..31
$length = Get-Random(15..31)

# use the begin block of foreach to initialize the variable $str.
#This block is executed once prior to processing each object.

0..$length | ForEach-Object -Begin {

    $str=$null
    # make an anonymous function

    $get = {Get-Random(0..9)}

} -Process {

    # set $str equal to a new random number plus itself.
    #Can invoke the scriptblock stored in $get with either & or .

    $str = "$(& $get)$str"

} -end {

    # output $str at the end. This block is executed once after processing all the objects.

    $str
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `$seed = $seed += $getRandomNum` inside the loop, you are in fact creating an array of random numbers. When sent to file (or console screen), each element of that array will be displayed on a separate line., so basically all you need to do is to join these elements with an empty string.

```
$times = 16..32 | Get-Random
$result = while ($times -gt 0) {   # capture the output in a variable (array)
    0..9 | Get-Random 
    $times--
}
-join $result | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Test\seed.txt'
```

Result is something like `2999639880330674452746`

<sup>P.S. If you don't want the file to end in a NewLine, you can add switch `-NoNewline` to the Out-File command</sup>